# String concatenation using + operator

Tags: c++, arrays, string, addition, c-strings

```
std::cout << "Please enter your first name: ";
std::string name;
std::cin >> name;
// build the message that we intend to write
const std::string greeting = "Hello, " + name + "!"; //LineA
std::cout << greeting;
```

PRODUCES:

> Hello,anyname_given !

But when I change the "LineA" to

```
const std::string greeting = "Hello, " + "Hello " + "!";
```

gives error

> HelloWorld.cpp:34:42: error: invalid operands of types 'const char [8]'
>     and'const char [6]' to binary 'operator+'
>     const std::string greeting = "Hello, " + "Hello" + "!";

Why it is saying that invalid operands types?

Comment: since "Hello, " is not a std::string

Comment: but @Prakash in first case also "Hello," is not std::string

Comment: @krishna the latter case there is no std::string object to evaluate the + operator.. you are trying to add the character arrays..

Comment: then you are saying that to evaluate there has to be atleast one operand string type .What about this case@Prakash
"Hello,"+"World"+name;

Comment: expressions evaluated from left to right. "Hello,"+ "World" is evaluated and then it tries to add the name.. but since "Hello," and "World" are both char arrays operator + can't evaluate ...

Answer (score 2):

std::operator+ can be applied on std::string objects but not on char[]..

"Hello, "  is a character array.

You can do the below to add,

```
 std::string hello = "Hello ,";
 std::string greeting = hello + name ;
```